# Default selected from dropdown list from mysql output

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am querying a mysql database and returning some user info including their access level. As the user level either 1 or 2 comes back from the database how do I have their user level selected using jQuery.

```
<select id="dropdown">
<option  value="1">Admin</option>
<option  value="2">General</option>
</select>
```

I want to set accesslevel to be what ever access level the user has:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dropdown").val('accesslevel');
});
```

Sorry but I am an absolute beginner. I tried to get access level from php variable name using this but its not working.

```
<?php $accesslevel; ?>
```

Comment: `<select>` holds the "name" attribute and not `<option>`.

Comment: You have try like `$("#dropdown").val('<?php echo $accesslevel; ?>');` ? I don't type this in answer form because i'm not sure this is what you want.

Comment: I tried exactly that and not working

Comment: <?php $accesslevel; ?> that's not the echo tag, <?= that's the echo tag, you may also use  <?php echo $accesslevel; ?>

Comment: The echo tag gives me a syntax error. The other method does not give a syntax error but it doesn't work.

Comment: @BarneyGorilla Are you sure that `$accesslevel` is set ?

Comment: yes I have $accesslevel = $row['Access'];

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to use jQuery for that, it can be handled with just PHP like this:

```
<?php

    echo '<select id="dropdown">';

    if ($accesslevel == 'admin') {

        echo '<option value="1" selected>Admin</option>';
        echo '<option value="2">General</option>';

    } else {

        echo '<option value="1">Admin</option>';
        echo '<option value="2" selected>General</option>';

    }

    echo '</select>';

?>
```

Comment: This would work although increases code length. Jquery answer would be nice as I thought I was close to what I need to get it to work.